# How to ping eth0 from eth1 on my linux machine?

Tags: ip, ethernet, ping

I have a linux machine with 2 ethernet ports(eth0 and eth1). eth0 is connected to a router which assigns it an IP address 192.168.1.2. eth1 is connected to a switch which doesn't have an IP. How do I ping eth0 from eth1?

Comment: could you explain why you want to ping one interface from another interface on the same machine?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `-I` parameter, eg.

```
# ping -I eth1 192.168.1.2
```

Comment: as the `#` suggests, one needs to be `root` to do that.

Answer (score 1):

If your eth1 doesnt have an IP, it will not be able to work with IP traffic (and ping / ICMP is IP traffic). Did I misunderstood your problem ?

Edit : I am not sure that I understand your network. Could you send a schema ?

If I understood correctly, you ahve eth0 configured with DHCP and eth1 configured manually. Are you sure that the address you have on eth1 is correct ? If you configured it as 10.0.0.1, you need to have y router with an interface in the same subnet, and the router has to be configured to route trafic from your 192.168.1.0/24 to you 10.0.0.0/24 networks.

Comment: You understood my problem. I assigned an IP using:
"ifconfig eth1 10.0.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 up".
But still I can't ping.

Comment: You understood my network correctly. What happens if I configure eth1 as 192.168.1.254? What more should I do to make the ping work?